L'adjectif ou l'expression relatif·ve à arc-en-ciel existe-t-iel ?
La question :
— étoile a pour adjectif stellaire
— arc-en-ciel a pour adjectif ???
Par quel mot remplacer les « ??? » ?
Sinon y a-t-il un néologisme, ou une expression équivalente ?

Complément suite à la réponse de None
Le mot ‘adjectif’ de ma question est trop restreint :
—  ce sont des mots, expressions, arts ou sciences relatives aux arcs-en-ciel, comme stellaire l'est à étoile…
— ou peut-être des verbes tel que étoilé ou constellé en dehors du néologisme arc-en-cielisé.

La nation arc-en ciel. Phrase prise dans le TLF  : « Le samedi, on pouvait voir des hommes battre la semelle dans les queues, devant les boutiques à enseignes arc-en-ciel, sur lesquelles on lisait : Débit d'alcool. E. Triolet ».

Il n'existe pas d'adjectif dérivé d'arc-en-ciel au sens où stellaire, donné en exemple par l'OP, dérive d'étoile.
Si un adjectif dérivé est nécessaire, le plus direct est irisé proposé par None. Si l'heure est à la préciosité, je vous signale une acception rare de prismatique: "comme la lumière issant d'un prisme". C'est le sens 2 dans l'entrée de fr.Wikt; elle comporte deux exemples, l'un littéraire, l'autre technique:

deux épaules rondes s’ourlèrent de lumière prismatique;
toutes [ces personnes] ap[p]erçoivent les Couleurs priſmatiques...

Dans le même ordre d'idées, la séquence des couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel constitue techniquement le spectre optique du Soleil, duquel dérive l'adjectif spectral. L'ennui, c'est que les différentes acceptions collisionnent: la couleur spectrale évoque plutôt le blême du 4ème cavalier que la queue du paon.

Cette définition n'est pas précieuse, mais scientifique et complète celle de photométéorique de @None. En raccourci/condensé : les photons qui traversent un prisme génèrent les couleurs prismatiques identiques à celles photométéoriques des arcs-en-ciel dont il est possible de connaître le rythme vibratoire de chaque rai spectral.

La définition elle-même n'est pas précieuse, certes. Encore que: elle est bien utile aux locuteurs qui veulent faire acte de préciosité. Utile, voire précieuse.

Préciosité à des connotations d'affectation, d'euphuisme https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/euphuisme et dans les synonymes de gongorisme, rassemblés par le Robert https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/gongorisme , inexistantes dans le mot précieux… P.S. :-) Merci de m'avoir permis de découvrir ces mots :-)

Dans la mythologie grecque Iris était la déesse de l'arc-en-ciel. C'est son nom qui a donné le nom « irisation » et l'adjectif « irisé ».

[...]
Un poète pieux, ennemi du sommeil,
Dans le creux de sa main prend cette larme pâle,
Aux reflets irisés comme un fragment d'opale,
Et la met dans son cœur loin des yeux du soleil.

(Baudelaire, Tristesses de la lune)
Irisé dans le TLF :

I. − Part. passé de iriser et emploi adj. Qui a les couleurs de l'arc-en-ciel, qui brille de reflets colorés. Perles, verre irisé(es). Bulle de plus en plus grosse, irisée et fragile (Jouve, Scène capit.,1935, p. 198). Les autres peintures ne seraient que des reflets plus ou moins irisés (Lhote, Peint. d'abord,1942, p. 30).

Il est vrai que le mot s'utilise peu dans le langage courant où on peut lui préférer l'adjectif arc-en-ciel. Il y a la « truite arc-en-ciel », la « nation arc-en-ciel »...
Arc-en-ciel dans le TLF :

II.− Emploi adj.
A.− Dans la lang. cour.
1- Dont les couleurs rappellent le prisme de l'arc-en-ciel

Exemple trouvé sur Cordial :

Une poignée de petites phrases aux journalistes et le voilà qui repartait, portant sur ses épaules le maillot arc-en-ciel comme s'il s'agissait d'une vieille pelisse. (Le Monde, 1995)


Post-réponse :
Après échanges en commentaires il s'avère que le mot recherché doit s'appliquer plus au phénomène physique qu'à l'objet arc-en-ciel en soi. L'arc-en-ciel est un photométéore ; en découle l'adjectif photométéorique dont j'ai effectivement trouvé quelques ocurrences, dont une dans un article* traduit de l'allemand. « Photométéore » et « photométéorique » ne se trouvent pas encore dans les dictionnaires courants, et il possible qu'ils aient été importés de l'allemand car ils sont mentionnés dès le XIXe siècle dans le Dictionnaire complet des langues française et allemande de Dominique-Joseph Mozin (1846).
* Approche d’une histoire du climat de l’Arc alpin et spécialement du Valais (Suisse) d’après les documents d’archives, 2013. 

J'aime bien le poème de Baudelaire, que j'avais oublié… De fait, l'adjectif de ma question est trop restreint, ce sont des mots, expressions, arts ou sciences relatives aux arcs-en-ciel, comme stellaire est un adjectif relatif aux étoiles… ou peut-être des verbes tel que étoilé ou constellé en dehors du néologisme arc-en-cielisé

@Personne Je ne comprends pas trop. La science qui étudie les arcs-en-ciel c'est la  spectroscopie, il existe l'adjectif spectroscopique. Un arc-en ciel est un phénomène photométéorique. Mais ça ne répond pas non plus à ton commentaire. À « ciel étoilé (constellé d'étoiles) » je fais correspondre un « ciel irisé ».

… photométéorique, je prends, Merci !! Je chercahais plutôt vers une référence littéraire, et, ta solution est la meilleure pour régler le problème ::--))

@Personne Bon je ne vois pas comment ça répond à la question ! Photométéorique peut s'appliquer à tout phénomène optique se  produisant dans l'atmosphère, il y en a peu mais il n'y a pas que les arcs-en-ciel. Alors que stellaire ne concerne que les étoiles, je ne vois pas le parallélisme que tu sembles chercher dans la question.  Je ne vois pas comment raccrocher ça à ma réponse !!!

@… !!! la réponse est dans mon commentaire de celle de François Jurain :-)

On trouve quelques rares arc-en-céleste (attesté depuis au moins 1892) et sa variante arcencéleste.

Calice changeant sous le déversement des essences lumineuses, le beau spectre simula le papillon, puis la fleur, puis une pâle statue surgissant d’un tombeau parmi des suaires, puis un tournoiement arc-en-céleste, puis des formes d’orchidées et de monstre des faunes sous-marines, dans une incessante cataracte de feux bleuâtres, glacés, diaprés d’or fauve [...]
Camille Mauclair, Le soleil des morts, 1898.


En équilibre sur son pied droit, Jérôme tend la jambe gauche avant d'allonger les bras. En m'observant en train d'imiter le phasianidé au plumage arc-en-céleste, le pédagogue ne masque guère sa gêne [...]
Rémi Dupré, Le Monde, 13 déc. 2012.


Quelques livres de tous ages 1832 - 2002 https://www.google.fr/search?tbm=bks&hl=fr&q=%22arc-en-c%C3%A9leste%22
